# What is the probability of this divisibility?

Tags: probability

Two positive integers  m and n are chosen at randon from the set of natural numbers.What is the probabilty that either one of them divides the other?My guess is that it is 0.Is my intuition correct or am I mistaken?

Comment: What does it mean to choose a positive integers at random from the set of natural numbers? For example, what is the probability of choosing 1?

Comment: "chosen at randon from the set of natural numbers" is undefined. What do you mean by that? Unrelated: Please explain your guess.

Comment: We  talk of  the probability of two random positive integers from the set of natural numbers being coprime .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we chose $m,n$ from $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ at random and independently, then the probability that $m\mid n$ is very approximately $$\frac {N+\frac N2+\frac N3+\ldots+\frac NN}{N^2} $$
(because for each $m$ there are approximately $\frac Nm$ multiples of $m$).
This is roughly $$ \frac {\ln N}N$$
and hence tends to $0$ as $N$ tends to infinity. In this sense (which is one way to talk about "pick a random integer") your guess is thus correct.

Comment: It is interesting to note that if F(N) is the no. of such ordered pairs (m,n) wher both m and n are  less or equal to N then F(N) behaves asymptotically like the prime no. function pi(N)